# Why does adding woff2 mimetype on web.config is not working on IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, woff2

After some research i've noticed that in order to use woff2 font types with IIS you need to set the following on the web project's web.config in order to avoid getting 404s from the server:

```
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff2"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
</staticContent>
```

Locally, this seem to work, but when the project is deployed on IIS, I keep getting 404s, what could be the cause of the issue? Thanks

Comment: Are you certain that the IIS version you are targeting is IIS 7 or above? Otherwise the web.config system.webServer sections (like staticContent) would be ignored in IIS 6 and below

Comment: Yeah target server is above IIS 7

Answer (score 0):

I had the same the problem today; I discovered the fonts were not included/added in my project.